# Stop NGINX from locally caching a directory

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, memory, cache

So, the issue I am currently facing is that NGINX on my system keeps caching huge video files in memory when a HTTP request is made. This is causing NGINX to be using 20GB+ of memory and me having to run `sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` *(clearing pagecache)* frequently to stop constant swapping. I have provided below the relevant configuration.

**nginx.conf**

```
location /protected/ {
    internal;
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/videos/;
}
```

**script.php**

```
function Download(){
    global $path, $fname;
    $file = "$path/$fname";
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file)); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fname.'"');
    header("X-Accel-Redirect: /protected/$fname");
    exit;
}
```

**What I have tried in nginx.conf:**

```
sendfile off;
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
proxy_no_cache 1;
proxy_cache_bypass 1;
open_file_cache off;
```

P.S: I am calculating the memory usage for these files using pcstat and fincore, these MP4 files are being 100% cached when being watched by a user and each are 5GB+ in size.

Comment: Are you sure it is nginx using 20GB+ memory? Dropping page caches doesn't affect nginx memory usage, it just removes files from cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can disable operating system caching for files served by nginx by using `directio <size>` setting. `<size>` is the threshold for file size, bigger files than that will be copied using DMA directly, and the files are not cached.

Comment: proxy_no_cache 1; afaik on or off is correct

Comment: Not in this case since there is no reverse proxy configured. `proxy_no_cache` only affects reverse proxy caching.

Comment: as you are not showing the full config we have to assum you use a proxy connection

Comment: `expires -1;` disables any caching try as it invalids any requests and also         `add_header                      'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';`
force REALLY to ignore any caching behavior

Comment: That is disabling HTTP caching. It does not affect nginx memory usage in any way.